# How to style a type=submit in a particular class/form(Not to all type=submit button) with css

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class="form_no_bullet">
  <li class="form_li_pad"><input name="password" type="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Confirm Password" required></li><br>
  <li class="form_li_pad"><input type="submit" value="Register"></li>
 </ul>
```

// It should apply on this specific class="form_li_pad" type=submit and other type=submit should not change

// this style is targeting all the type=submit button/inputs
CSS

```
input[type=text] {

}

 input[type=text]:focus {
}

input[type=submit] {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo for you, see if this works. Read more about `selectors` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```css
input[type=submit]{
  color: blue;
}

input[type=submit].xyz{
  color: red;
}

.any_class input[type=submit]{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value='Submit'>

<input type="submit" class="xyz" value='Submit with class'>

<div class="any_class">
<input type="submit" class="xyz" value='Submit within a class'>
</div>
```